# petapoco insert problem

Tags: orm, petapoco

I have a class defined like so:

```
public class Location
{
    public Location()
    {
        Meetings = new List<Meeting>();
    }

    public virtual int ID { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }

}
```

And the database table for this is just “locations” with an ID and a Name property.

Some other table “meetings” has a foreign key back to this table.  And it is beyond the scope of what I’m trying to work with in this example, yet I think it is causing PetaPoco to fail…

I’m trying to use PetaPoco to insert a new location into the database like this:

```
    public int AddLocation(string name)
    {
        var newLocation = new Location{Name = name};
        var db = new PetaPoco.Database(_connectionString);
        db.Insert("locations", "ID", newLocation);
        return newLocation.ID;
    }
```

And it is throwing an error like so:

> {"No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[NHRepoTemplate.sampleUsage.sampleModel.Meeting,
>   NHRepoTemplate, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>   to a known managed provider native
>   type."}

It seems to me like the existence of the child collection causes PetaPoco to not be able to do the insert, but...  there must be a way to tell it to "ignore" that, right?

Comment: Adding the attribute that Jon mentioned is correct. The Meeting class should then have a LocationId property that you can then use to reference back to this location

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting this over your Meetings property:

```
[PetaPoco.Ignore]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `[ExplicitColumns]` attribute above your petapoco class, all properties that do not have the `[Column]` attribute will be ignored